# Conditional Formatting in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet with a series of rows A1 - H1 etc and a drop down list which lives in H1, I would really like to change the cell styles of all the cells between A1 - H1 based on the value in H1.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've had little success with conditional formatting so far.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: 2007. So far i've got to =INDIRECT("M"&ROW())=1 which works, but I can't get =INDIRECT("M"&ROW())=Status to work for some reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nailed it. Select the range of cells you want to format and then choose conditional formatting > manage rules. Create a new rule and choose "use a formula to determine which cells to format"

Enter =INDIRECT("M"&ROW())="Old" where M is the column you want to detect the value in and "Old" is the value you want the change based on.

Comment: Good job!  I was going to give up but I'll put this one in my archives.